# Adding JButton with ActionListener to a JTabbedPane: ActionListener not working

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtabbedpane

New poster here; if I'm breaking any rules/screwing anything up, just tell me and I'll take the post down.

I have a MainMenu JFrame with a JPanel (mainMenu) inside it. mainMenu has one button that changes the display to the JTabbedPane Instructions. This part is working fine.

The problem comes in when I'm trying to add a button and new tab to Instructions. Although the new buttons and tab are added to the Instructions class, the button doesn't actually do anything despite having an ActionListener for that button.

Below are the Instructions class (extends JTabbedPane) and MainMenu (extends JFrame) for reference.

Thanks in advance.

Directly below: MainMenu class
`

```
/**
 * @Author Small Snake Studios (Nathan Lee)
 * @Date Feb 28, 2017
 * @Version 1.0
 * @Description This program is a JPanel for the Blockfinder Express game. Mostg of the work done this week has been in graphics rather than in coding this week.
 */

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
/**
 * This is a JPanel that represents the main menu of the program. Each of the buttons open up another JPanel in the main JFrame,
 * each JPanel representing a different screen. This JFrame is the main menu and you can open the other JPanels through this one. 
 * Because it's a JFrame, it can hold and control the rest of the windows (splash screen, main menu, credits, the main game, instructions,
 * high scores and exit. 
 **/

public class MainMenu extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

    /**
     * This is a serialVersionUID. It is generated to avoid errors/warnings.
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3088890058631223710L;
    /*Name          use                                                                         type
     * splashScreen creates a splash screen that shows an animation                         SplashScreen 
     * mainGame     a JPanel representing the main game                                     MainGame  
     * instructions a JPanel representing the instructions screen                           Instructions 
     * quit         a JPanel representing the quit screen                                   Quit
     * credits      a JPanel representing the credits screen                                Credits
     * mainMenu     a JPanel representing the main menu (built into the MainMenu class)     JPanel*/
    SplashScreen splashScreen = new SplashScreen ();
    JTabbedPane instructions = new Instructions ();
    JPanel credits = new Credits ();
    JPanel highScores = new HighScores ();
    JPanel mainMenu = new JPanel ();
    JMenuBar myMenus  = new JMenuBar ();
    JButton play = new JButton ("Play!");
    JButton howToPlay = new JButton ("Learn!");
    JButton leaderboards = new JButton ("Leaderboards!");
    JButton creds = new JButton ("Credits!");
    JMenu quitMenu = new JMenu ("Quit");
    JMenuItem quitMenuItem = new JMenuItem ("Quit");

    public MainMenu () //constructor
    {
        super ("Blockfinder Express"); //constructor adds all of these buttons to the JPanel
        init ();
    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae)
    {   
        Frame f = null;
        if (ae.getActionCommand ().equals ("Play!"))
        {  if (f == null)
        {
            remove (mainMenu);
            f = new Frame ();
            repaint ();
        }
        }
        if (ae.getActionCommand ().equals("Quit"))
        {
            dispose ();
            f.dispose ();
        }
        if (ae.getActionCommand ().equals ("Return to Menu"))
        {
            System.out.println("returning to menu");
            remove (instructions); 
            add (mainMenu);
            repaint ();
            revalidate ();
        }
        if (ae.getActionCommand ().equals ("Learn!"))
        {
            add (instructions);
            JPanel exit = new JPanel (); 
            JButton returnButton = new JButton ("Return to Menu");
            exit.add(returnButton);
            instructions.add("Exit", exit);
            remove (mainMenu);
            repaint ();
            System.out.println ("Functional");
        }   
    }
    public void init ()
    {
        play.addActionListener(this);
        howToPlay.addActionListener(this);
        leaderboards.addActionListener (this);
        creds.addActionListener (this); 
        mainMenu.add (play);
        mainMenu.add (howToPlay);
        mainMenu.add(leaderboards);
        mainMenu.add(creds);
        myMenus.add(quitMenu);
        quitMenu.add(quitMenuItem);
        quitMenuItem.addActionListener(this);
        setJMenuBar (myMenus);
        setSize (1000,900);
        setResizable (false);
        setVisible (true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        add (splashScreen);
        splashScreen.animate ();
        remove (splashScreen);
        add (mainMenu);
        repaint ();
        revalidate ();
    }

    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        MainMenu mm = new MainMenu ();
    }
}
```

`
Below: Instructions class

```
    /**
 * @author Nathan 
 * @version 1.0 
 * @studio Small Snake Studios 
 * @purpose: This is a JPanel representing the instructions screen. It functions by using a picture 
 * the instructions screen as the way to display it on the JPanel. The driver class/main menu 
 * adds an exit button to the JPanel so I can implement an ActionListener that closes this
 * tab from there. Probably works better that way, too. Uses a CardLayout to go from one
 * instruction page to another, allowing for easy readability and preventing me from having
 * to cram a lot of info in one screen. The pages of the CardLayout are done via nested classes 
 * so I can implement paint and graphics in each of them. 
 * 
 * Things to do:
 * - Add actual pictures for the three instructions screen
 * - Run this code with everything else to ensure it works
 */

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;   

public class Instructions extends JTabbedPane{
        class FirstScreen extends JPanel 
    {   
        /**
             * 
             */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -2674891692847531892L;
        BufferedImage instructions; 
        public FirstScreen ()
        {
            importInfo ();
            repaint ();
        }
        public void importInfo (){
        try
        {
            instructions = ImageIO.read (new File ("Instructions1.png"));
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
        }
        }
        public void paint (Graphics g)
        {
            g.drawImage (instructions, 0, 0, null);
        }
    }
        class SecondScreen extends JPanel 
    {   
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -2840353661877108337L;
        BufferedImage instructions; 
        public SecondScreen ()
        {
            importInfo ();
            repaint ();
        }
        public void importInfo ()
        {
            try
            {
            instructions = ImageIO.read (new File ("Instructions2.png"));
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
            }
        }
        public void paint (Graphics g)
        {
            g.drawImage (instructions, 0, 0, null);
        }
    }
        class ThirdScreen extends JPanel
        {   
        /**
             * 
             */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -394248748993045880L;
        BufferedImage instructions; 
        public ThirdScreen ()
        {
            importInfo ();
            repaint ();
        }
        public void importInfo ()
        {
            try
            {
                instructions = ImageIO.read (new File ("Instructions3.png"));
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
            }
        }      
        public void paint (Graphics g)
        {
            g.drawImage (instructions, 0, 0, null);
        }
        }
public Instructions ()
{
    super ();
    FirstScreen card1 = new FirstScreen ();
    SecondScreen card2 = new SecondScreen (); 
    ThirdScreen card3 = new ThirdScreen ();
    add ("Page 1", card1); 
    add ("Page 2", card2);
    add ("Page 3", card3);
}
}
```

Comment: Which button do you mean? The returnButton has no listener attached

Comment: Yeah, I'm dumb. Idk how I forgot to add the listener :/ thanks!

Comment: No problem, happens all the time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returnButton you are referring to has no actionListener attached. So just add it.

```
JButton returnButton = new JButton ("Return to Menu");
returnButton.addActionListener(this);
```